# How to update a collection based on another collection without joins?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that looks like:

```
transactions
{
  "_id": ...,
  "status": "new"
}


processed

{
  "_id": id value from collection above
}
```

So I want to update the transaction collection status value to "processed", if there is record in the processed collection.

The processed id value is from the transactions collection id.

Is this possible to do in mongo console or I have to do this using code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a `$merge` stage in aggregation.

- remove all fields except the _id
- add any fields with the updated value
- merge with the other collection

```
db.procecessed.aggregate([
   {$project:{_id:1}},
   {$addFields:{status:"processed"}},
   {$merge:"transactions"}
])
```

Comment: these types of queries must be expensive?  used only for reports I guess right?

Comment: if you limit the number of documents examined from the processed collection, perhaps by timestamp, it wouldn't be terribly expensive.